# What's the efficient way to query items in this many-to-many relationship? (Rails)

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql

I'm trying to find if there's an efficient way to query my DB using Rails/AR. I'm somewhat new, so thanks for any tips.

I'm trying to query all the items that belong to a particular Category. When a user goes to /categories/5, they should see all the items that are in Category-5.

Models:

- Item
- Label  *(aka Items_Categories)*
- Category

Label is the join-table. I'm successfully querying all Labels that are from the Category. I'm just not sure how to then query all the Items from those Labels. In other words, I've made it to the join table, just not sure how to bridge to the other side.

Label schema:

- id
- category_id
- item_id

Here's what my controller has so far:

```
 categoryLabels = Label.where(category_id: params[:id])
 categoryItems = ???
 render json: categoryItems
```

Here's an example of the query I'm looking at, trying to decide how to get the items that have a Category of 5. I figure  "extract" an (array?) of each of the items that are in the given category. I'm tempted to loop over categoryLabels, but I'm not sure if that is correct/efficient.

```
select * from labels;
id  |   category_id   |  item_id
1            5              22
2            5              17
3            2              50
```

Comment: what about item table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If Label does not contain additional fields, you do not need it in the controller.
Just try this:

```
category = Category.find(params[:id]) # get category
items = category.items # get items
render json: items
```

Read more about many-to-many methods here http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-and-belongs-to-many-association

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for, thank you. And I'll check out your link now. I'd come across it before but wasn't sure if it covered queries (versus, for example, the initial setup of the relationship). Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

Try to pluck the ActiveRelation object to retrieve an array, like this:

`categoryItems = categoryLabels.pluck(:item_id) # [22, 17, 50]`

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `Item table` as

***Items(item_id,item_id)***

```
SELECT Items.`item_name`
FROM
Labels INNER JOIN Items.`item_id` = Labels.`item_id`
WHERE Labels.category_id=5
```

Hope this helps.